# Inner Join not giving results in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql, hadoop2

I am trying to join 4 talbles. One is the main table and joinging 3 other tables with this main table. Please see data looks like as follows:

[image]

[image]

Expected output.

[image]

Here is the query I developed and its always returning 0 rows.

```
select COALESCE(TableB.Date, TableC.Date, TableD.Date), 
       COALESCE(count(key1),0), 
       COALESCE(count(key2),0), 
       COALESCE(count(key3),0)
FROM TableA A JOIN TableB B on A.Date = B.Date 
JOIN TableC C on A.Date = C.Date
JOIN TableD D on A.Date = D.Date
Group by COALESCE(TableB.Date, TableC.Date, TableD.Date);
```

when I ran individual query on each table(see below query) with TableA, it returns the data but when I am joining with all 3 tables, its not retuning any data.

```
select TableB.Date, count(key1)
  FROM TableA A JOIN TableB B on A.Date = B.Date 
Group by TableB.Date;
```

I am not sure what's going wrong and could some one help to understand where is the issue in join query.

Thanks,
Babu

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried suggested change but it didn't work. Moreover if change the way you suggested, date from C table may not be there in D table.

Answer (score 1):

Do the joins in the subquery, then do grouping, e.g.,

```
with join_table as (select COALESCE(TableB.Date, TableC.Date, TableD.Date) as Date, 
    key1, key2, key3
    FROM TableA A JOIN TableB B on A.Date = B.Date 
    JOIN TableC C on A.Date = C.Date
    JOIN TableD D on A.Date = D.Date
)
select Date,
       COALESCE(count(key1),0), 
       COALESCE(count(key2),0), 
       COALESCE(count(key3),0)
  from join_table
 group by Date
```

In fact, you don't need to coalesce the join keys in the inner join.

Comment: Thank you for your response and I will try this and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this -

```
select A.Date, 
       COALESCE(count(key1),0), 
       COALESCE(count(key2),0), 
       COALESCE(count(key3),0)
FROM TableA A 
LEFT JOIN TableB B on A.Date = B.Date 
LEFT JOIN TableC C on A.Date = C.Date
LEFT JOIN TableD D on A.Date = D.Date
Group by A.Date;
```

I used left join instead of inner join because we need all data from Table A. Also first column should come from table A which is driver table.

Comment: suppose date is there in tableA but if it is not there in any other table, we don't need that date from tableA.

Comment: you mentioned this 'One is the main table and joining 3 other tables with this main table.' so I assumed table A is main one. If you say you dont want the date which is in Table A and not in any other table then you need to add a where condition to my SQL `WHERE COALESCE(TableB.Date, TableC.Date, TableD.Date) is NOT NULL`.

Comment: In that case we can't use Left Join right. My query exactly same as you provided except I used inner join. With inner join, I am not getting any result and if I use FULL OUTER JOIN, I am getting weird results.

Comment: Inner join will result those records which are present in `all` tables. full outer join will result all data `present/absent`. It all depends on your requirement. What you need ? 1. all data from all tables ? (go for full join) 2. all data from certain tables ? (go for left join) 3. all matching data from all tables + all non matched data from all tables ?

Comment: Either case it is not working. I need all  dates from all tables if it is present in main table. I think that means it is Inner join to all tables with main table. I tried it and its not giving any results(query same as what you suggested and what I have given in my explanation. Not sure why it is not working. Thank you for taking time and responding to my questions. Really appreciate it.

Comment: is it possible the date has time too? can you pls try joining only on date - `to_date(A.date) = to_date(B.date)` ?

Comment: Yes, we are doing with date itself. No time included.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for full outer join .
Here will be sample code

```
select COALESCE(a.Date, b.Date, c.Date,d.Date), 
       COALESCE(sum(key1),0), 
       COALESCE(sum(key2),0), 
       COALESCE(sum(key3),0)

(select distinct date as date from tableA ) as a
full outer join 
(select  date ,sum(key1) as key1 from tableB group by date) as b
on a.date=b.date
full outer join
(select  date ,sum(key2) as key2 from tableB group by date) as c
on a.date=c.date
full outer join
(select  date ,sum(key3) as key2 from tableB group by date) as d
on a.date=d.date
Group by COALESCE(a.Date, b.Date, c.Date,d.Date);`
```

Comment: Thank you for your response and I will try this and let you know.